# Choose one of the Xpath in the XSL to display element value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a XML , which contains 3 elements. Depending on the XML type , at a time only one of the Xpath would be present.

I have to use XSL to map these elements (whichever is present) to a single Element. I am able to do it using Xsl:choose. I am not satisfied with the solution . I find it more as a hack.

My Input XML schema is

```
  <test>
      ....
      <calDays />
      <busDays />
      <maxBusDays />
 </test>
```

My REquired Output XML schema is

```
<output>
      <days />
</output>
```

XSL currently I am using is

```
<xsl:element name = "days">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test= "calDays">
            <xsl:value-of select = "calDays"/></xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test= "busDays">
            <xsl:value-of select = "busDays"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select = "maxBusDays"/></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:element>
```

If My Input XML is

```
 <test>
     <calDays> 30 </calDays>
 </test>
```

then I want my o/p XML to be

```
 <output>
        <days> 30</days>
 </output>
```

Does anyone has any other solution for this kind of condition?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="test">
  <output>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="(calDays[normalize-space()] | busDays[normalize-space()] | maxBusDays)[1]"/>
  </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="calDays | busDays | maxBusDays">
  <days><xsl:value-of select="."/></days>
</xsl:template>
```